# Graphviz and Curly/Wavy lines

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot

Is there a way to get curly/wavy lines between two nodes in graphviz/dot?

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this is to use a combination of graphviz dot, and the newer LaTeX drawing tools TikZ and PGF. Kjell Magne Fauske has an amazing [gallery](http://www.fauskes.net/code/dot2tex/gallery/) of the things that you can do by using these tools together.

The most significant demo for your question is the [pgf-snake](http://www.fauskes.net/code/dot2tex/gallery/pgf-snakes/). The image from that demo is reproduced here for completeness.

[image: Twisted Edges for graphviz/TikZ/PGF]

Comment: Link to pgf-snake is broken. Another link that answer the question is on http://dot2tex.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customization_guide.html